# List of all un-erasable names in Tanakh

Tags: shemos-sacred-names, safrus

There are certain words in Tanakh that refer to God (*shemot* or *azkarot*) that have special rules: they cannot be erased and they require special sanctification before a *sofer* writes them. These include יהוה, אל, אדני, אלהים, and so on (see [Keset HaSofer 11:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Keset_HaSofer.11.5)). But they only have this status when referring to God. For example, אלהי נחור in [Gen 31:53](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.31.53?lang=bi) is not considered holy (see [Soferim 4:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Tractate_Soferim.4.5?lang=bi), and more generally chapter 4 for more background).

Is there a list of all words in Tanakh that have this status? (Equivalently: a full list of words that are usually holy combined with a complete list of occurrences of the usually-holy words where the word isn't holy.) I know that Soferim 4:5–9 contains many examples, but I imagine that it's not a full list. Additionally, I know that there are multiple opinions about some words (like אל in בית אל, or אשר in אהיה אשר אהיה), so a list that indicates the disagreements would be ideal.

Note: there are other names that are considered holy but may still be erased (see Soferim 5:17–18 for examples). Although a separate full list of those would also be welcome, that is not the focus of this question.

Comment: These are called רשימות הספיקות (or something very similar) and were only composed of the ~100 places in Torah where someone might be confused. No one before the modern era bothered to write down all the obvious places. There's one in the back of every classic tikkun sofrim, and all classic scribal works like keset hasofer, kol yaakov, etc.

Comment: (In the modern era a sofer is always copying from a computer generated tikkun with nice color indicators and such for all the potential names regarding their status (kodesh, chol, or safek) relegating these lists to study purposes only.)

Comment: @DoubleAA Someone clearly bothered to write down all the obvious places for Torah, so why not Nach? (I don't see one at the back of Kol Yaakov, and I don't see any non-Torah comments in Keset HaSofer.)

Comment: @DoubleAA Those who generate the tikkunim clearly have a list...

Comment: R. Menachem Lonzano didn't even bother clarifying the spelling of the words in Nakh and you wonder why no one worked out all the sfekot in shemot?? It was 'useless' info.

Comment: Those who generate the modern tikkunim either asked their LOR when in doubt or probably marked any doubtful-to-them name as a safek. You can ask them if you want; they're still alive. I'm just pointing out there's no longstanding masorah to most of those decisions, so take them for what it's worth.

Comment: I don't know if you realize this, but for names marked 'safek' the scribe sanctifies them with a stipulation that it only applies if the name is holy (מקדש על תנאי) so practically there is an out for all the places we're not sure about.

Comment: @DoubleAA Yes, kiddush al tnai I'm aware of. I realise that if a metaken comes with a different list of safek than the sofer, they might be erasing something that was mekudash al tnai without realising it... So I had hoped for some more centralised authority.

Comment: That's a pretty farfetched case but a good magia would understand how to handle it. Remember in 99% of cases the name is obviously kodesh or chol and 99% of scrolls-with-shemos are not nakh and this would have to be a major edit on a rarely looked at scroll when the sofer is unknown to ask. Even in Torah there are a few active disputes if on should mekaddesh al tnai or not so again a good magia should know how to handle it

Comment: @DoubleAA Here's a less farfetched case: someone wants to print out a source sheet but wants to remove the shemos. Which words do I care about?

Answer (score 2):

There is a sefer called "Melekhet ha-Ḳodesh" (מלאכת הקודש) which is dedicated to precisely this topic.

It was written by [Rabbi Elazar Fleckeles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elazar_Fleckeles), a student of [Rabbi Yechezkel Landau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yechezkel_Landau) (the author of the "Noda BeYehuda").

The first edition of the sefer can be [found here](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/20653).

The old edition is difficult to read, and it was typeset in a nice new edition, which appeared in 5745/1985, and can be found in the Otzar Hachachmah program, [and on line](https://tablet.otzar.org/book/book.php?book=176906&pagenum=1).

Comment: That sefer only talks about the Torah, as far as I can tell at a cursory flip-through..

Comment: @magicker72 You are correct, that this sefer does not cover Nach (Neviim & Kesuvim), however on the Torah, he's very comprehensive, and he lays down a general approach for dealing with words that there exists disagreements regarding their status.

Comment: @magicker72 There is no work like this on Nakh ttbomk

Comment: @magicker I just heard today that a new edition of a work like this is supposed to be coming out soon (or maybe was just published) that covers Nakh. I haven't seen it of course yet.

Comment: @DoubleAA Wonderful to hear! Know a name (author, sefer title) that I should be on the lookout for?

Comment: @magicker72 The 'modern encyclopedia' on the topic was 'nekadesh et shimkha' by a R Chaim Farkash (sp?) who collects from all the acharonim on every case and he asked R Elyashiv for psak on all them (and came out pretty consistently strict; which isn't crazy since there's little to lose by using the tnai). Apparently he's publishing a new edition or second volume or something that covers Nakh too. I suspect R Elyashiv (now z"l) didn't managed to participate, though I guess we'll have to see what he did instead.

Comment: @DoubleAA Great, thank you very much!